# ssbmod single sideband modulation artifacts

Tags: modulation, amplitude

```
clc; clear all; close all;
[c,fs]=audioread('60hz.wav')

r=ssbmod(c,160, fs)
r=r/max(max(abs(r)))

audiowrite('artifacts.wav',r,fs,'BitsPerSample',24)
```

I am trying to understand what causes the artifacts such as the one example in the picture below...This happens when the audio sample I am processing is 142157 samples in size, but if I use multiples of 44100 sample chunks of 60 hz sinewav I won't get that upper side band that is present in the picture below, the obvious Hilbert Transform is in play but what aspect of it is causing the artifact is what I am trying to find out...
this is the code for ssbmod:

```
y = x .* cos(2 * pi * Fc * t + ini_phase) + ...
        imag(hilbert(x)) .* sin(2 * pi * Fc * t + ini_phase);
```

[image: 60hz sinewav]